# How google Analytics will calculate page views when 10 computers connected in same network

Tags: google-analytics

i want to know as following informations

1.How google Analytic s will calculate page views
2.sessions.
3.users

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal the data is collected per client, not per network. I.e. the tracking code generates a clientid per browser (or client program) that is stored in a cookie per browser, and this is used to aggregate pageviews into sessions and users.

Geo information (and IP filtering) will of course be the same for all users that share an external IP, but other than that there will be no effect on the reports.

Comment: Why are you answering terrible off topic questions?

Comment: Because while I do not think this is well asked the question from the title (not the question body) seemed to be a real question (i.e. does NAT make a difference to the way GA collects data) and I am not sure this should be off topic .

Comment: How Google performs some action is absolutely *not* on topic.  You're encouraging this kind of fail.  Please, feel free to answer general questions on sites like quora.

Comment: This is a question how the GA tracking code works. A server logfile analyzer might report users with  common IP as one single user, GA will not  due to the way the tracking is implemented (and  that is in code). I take no grudge if someone decides that this answer should be deleted, but I will not do it myself since i maintain this is on topic.